# How to get Flutter web to listen on 127.0.0.1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to get my Flutter app to work on web but I need it running on a specific hostname.
When I run flutter `run -d chrome` it opens it on http://[::1]:57402/#/ (or some other random port)

If I change it http://localhost:57402/#/ it is still working as expected.

But now if I change it to http://127.0.0.1:57402/#/ I get a connection refused error. So if I need to change the hosts file to use a different name, that's also not working (I'm assuming because the 127.0.0.1 ip that I'm using in the hosts file is not working)

So any idea why this is happening or how can I make it work?

Comment: Well... I just found out (stupid me) that I can use ::1 in my hosts file as well... so I solved my main problem. Not sure if I should delete this question though, as the 127.0.0.1 problem remains...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can specify host with `web-hostname` and port with `web-port` parameters:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-hostname 127.0.0.1 --web-port 8888
```

The most reliable source of information is the `flutter tools` [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/run.dart).

Comment: Thank you, I found the web-port option somewhere, but not the web-hostname. Is this in the docs somewhere?

Comment: It's hard to remember the source.